# Loading Resulting layers

Tags: qgis, raster, batch

I'm wondering how long it normally takes to "load resulting layers" after performing a batch process for overviews on QGIS.

I have a large raster dataset that will ultimately be merged and need to build the pyramids beforehand. The batch process ran successfully within like 5 seconds but it's  been a few hours.

```
........

Processing algorithm 36/36…
Algorithm Build overviews (pyramids) starting…
Input parameters:
{'CLEAN': True,
'FORMAT': 0,
'INPUT': 'Ov_iD0A_L01_R000005A2_C0000025D',
'LEVELS': '2 4 8 16',
'RESAMPLING': 0}

GDAL command:
gdaladdo E:/Imagery/Coastal_GA/Raster_Catalog/Coastal_GA.Overviews/Coastal_Imagery.Overviews/Ov_iD0A_L01_R000005A2_C0000025D.tif -r nearest -clean 2 4 8 16
GDAL command output:
Algorithm Build overviews (pyramids) correctly executed…
Execution completed in 0.11 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': 'E:/Imagery/Coastal_GA/Raster_Catalog/Coastal_GA.Overviews/Coastal_Imagery.Overviews/Ov_iD0A_L01_R000005A2_C0000025D.tif'}

Loading resulting layers
Batch execution completed in 5.61 seconds
```

Comment: Is it faster if you load the output layers manually? Also, it can help to un-check "render" (bottom-right corner of QGIS project window) before loading many large raster layers into a project.